# ColdFusion debugging on a Macbook Pro

Tags: coldfusion

I installed CF on a Macbook Pro and turned on debugging.
In the Debugging IP Addresses section, I clicked on "Add Current" and it added

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0

So far, so good - the debugging info was displaying at the bottom of index.cfm.

But then inexplicably, it went away.  I clicked "Add Current" again and this time it added:

fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1

Do you think this is going to continue?

What do you think caused the leading 0 to change into fe80?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that it is just in reference to localhost using IPv6 syntax. But, if you are on localhost you can just remove the IP addresses all together. If it really bugs you, can just add 127.0.0.1 instead.

Comment: I usually just disable ipv6 on my local desktop. It's superfluous and gives me little quirks and fits like this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find some details about the fe80 address here: https://superuser.com/questions/241642/what-is-the-relevance-of-fe801lo0-localhost-in-etc-hosts.

I typically stick with 127.0.0.1.

Comment: An answer that requires the reader to go to another site to get any useful information (even if that site is within the Stack Exchange network) is not really an answer.